# SSMS - SQL Azure v12 preview - unknown property IsNativelyCompiled

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssms

When I try to view stored procedures in a SQL Azure database (V12 preview) in Management Studio (2014) I get the following error.

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> unknown property IsNativelyCompiled
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

Since its in preview I guess that it will be fixed, but is there anyone else who have seen this and in that case have any workarounds until its fixed by MS?

EDIT:
It works against on-premise 2014 installations so it seems like its only applies for SQLAzure V12.

Comment: That is very strange because SSMS 2014 is aware of natively compiled procedures. They exist starting with 2014. Do you have preview software on your machine?

Comment: No I dont, also made sure that no plugins are enabled that perhaps could have caused this behaviour.

Comment: Did a repair of SSMS but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution for me was to download the lastest cumulative update to SQL Server from http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com.es/ (CU5 at the time of writing).

Comment: Yes this update is required (until SP comes out) in order to work with SQL Azure V12. See more details on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/archive/2014/12/18/sql-server-2014-management-studio-updated-support-for-the-latest-azure-sql-database-update-v12-preview.aspx

Comment: Is this something that needs to be installed on the machine using SSMS, or the actual server?  I'm not finding a way to do this update in Azure...

Comment: What should I do if I only have SSMS Studio installed? The update does not install if SQL Server is not installed.