# SQL Server Management Studio 2014: Unable to view stored procedures on Azure SQL Database V12

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I have updated SQL Server Management Studio to the latest version at time of writing - 12.0.4432.0 - this is SP1 with CU3 and additional bug fixes. My Azur SQL Database version is 12.0.2000.8

I can not view any stored procedures through the GUI, when I try I get this error (all other functionality appears to be working normally):

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> unknown property IsNativelyCompiled (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

Help>About

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.4432.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                        12.0.4432.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.17801
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                        6.1.7601
```

Comment: When you open SSMS, what do you get for the version when you select Help.. About? IsNativelyCompiled is a 2014 edition and beyond concept so my gut feeling is that you are accidently opening a previous version of SSMS

Comment: The latest version of SSMS is 13.0.700.242, which can be downloaded here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @TonyRogerson I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014 Version 12.0.4432.0 as I said above.

Comment: @JosephIdziorek I would like to solve this in 2014 - not using a pre-release version of 2016. It shouldn't be a problem in 2014.

Comment: In SSMS can you go into Help..About and supply these two pieces of information please: Component Name: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and Microsoft .NET Framework - I want to make sure you aren't reporting the build number of the database engine you are connecting to rather that the version of SSMS you are actually using - please check and supply through Help..About - many thanks T

Comment: @TonyRogerson I'm aware of how to check my management studio version, I already have and posted it twice. As I said above Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.4432.0  -  Posted all details from Help>About in the original post above.

Comment: Your MDAC is a very old version, checking my SSMS here it's Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)  10.0.10240.16384.

Comment: @Ryan, I verified that this works with the latest version of SSMS @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx. and though I know youre trying to get this working on 2014, on this msdn page it does state that, "This release also provides the greatest level of support for working with the latest cloud features in Azure SQL Database."

Comment: Check this post out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690417/ssms-sql-azure-v12-preview-unknown-property-isnativelycompiled

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, I have download the service pack 1 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=46694) and I resolve

Comment: I was facing the same and it worked for me. I hope Question owner will mark it as the correct answer soon