# SSMS - Cannot View Stored Procedures in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, sqlconnection

My SSMS came with my SQL Server 2014 which I installed in June 2016, its version information given by @@version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) 
    Feb 20 2014 20:04:26 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

I created a SQL Server service on Azure, its config page is:
[image]

And its version information given by @@version is:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    Oct 18 2016 13:39:34 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
```

Now I have problems in viewing the stored procedures residing in my Azure database through SSMS, the error is exactly as that in this question: [SQL Server Management Studio 2014: Unable to view stored procedures on Azure SQL Database V12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914039/sql-server-management-studio-2014-unable-to-view-stored-procedures-on-azure-sql)

and this: 
[SSMS - SQL Azure v12 preview - unknown property IsNativelyCompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690417/ssms-sql-azure-v12-preview-unknown-property-isnativelycompiled)

I followed the solution. I downloaded the latest patch:

> 3188778 Cumulative update package 2 (CU2) for SQL Server 2014 Service
>   Pack 2

from this link: http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.co.nz/.

But I cannot install it, I got an error as:

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: According to the message you need to first have version 12.2.5000. But you might be better off just installing the latest SSMS (SQL 2016)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest install SQL Server Management Studio 2016.

login with admin account or any account which has admin access in azure sql server

Did you tried creating new account?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was using SQL server management studio 2014. Because compatibility levels are different in SQL Server 2014 and 2017. You should install SQL server 2017 (the latest version) and this works for me. Or you can install service pack of SQL server 2014.